# WebApi2 PUT with XML Source not working (works fine with JSON source)

Tags: asp.net, xml, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am using Postman to test a WebApi method and I'm running into an issue with XML.

My WebApi2 controller is defined with the following put method:

```
// PUT: api/DetailAttributes/5
[ResponseType(typeof(void))]
public IHttpActionResult PutDetailAttribute(int id, DetailAttribute detailAttribute)
{
    // Processing code is here...

    return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
}
```

When I PUT the following JSON, everything works as expected:

```
{
  "Id": 27,
  "AttributeTypeId": 1,
  "JobDetailId": 8,
  "Name": "Attribute update from JSON Post",
  "Value": "No error, just testing WebApi post for Attribute with JSON source.",
  "ModifiedBy": "some person"
}
```

However, when I PUT the following XML, the AttributeTypeId property is getting set to 0, even though I set it to 1, like so:

```
<DetailAttribute xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/DatafeedDashboard.Data">
<Id>27</Id>
<AttributeTypeId>1</AttributeTypeId>
<JobDetailId>8</JobDetailId>
<ModifiedBy>some person</ModifiedBy>
<Name>Attribute from XML Posttt</Name>
<Value>No error, just testing WebApi post for Attribute with XML source.</Value>
</DetailAttribute>
```

Here is the exact message that Postman sent to my web server (I also tried setting it to text/xml, but it had the same result):

```
PUT /Dashboard/api/DetailAttributes/27 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:58130
Content-Type: application/xml
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 07172181-fc03-5696-189f-4178b5645384

&lt;DetailAttribute xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/DatafeedDashboard.Data"&gt;
&lt;Id&gt;27&lt;/Id&gt;
&lt;AttributeTypeId&gt;1&lt;/AttributeTypeId&gt;
&lt;JobDetailId&gt;8&lt;/JobDetailId&gt;
&lt;ModifiedBy&gt;some person&lt;/ModifiedBy&gt;
&lt;Name&gt;Attribute from XML Posttt&lt;/Name&gt;
&lt;Value&gt;No error, just testing WebApi post for Attribute with XML source.&lt;/Value&gt;
&lt;/DetailAttribute&gt;
```

When I debug my application and inspect what is being passed in, here is what I see for the JSON request:

[image: JSON Result]

Here is what it looks like for the XML PUT request:

[image]

As you can see, it sets the value to 0, instead of 1, which is what I would expect.

Also, notice how the value of JobDetailId is being passed correctly for both JSON and XML, so it doesn't seem to have anything to do with the `int` data type.

Here is the Code for the DetailAttribute entity as generated by Entity Framework:

```
public partial class DetailAttribute
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public DetailAttribute()
    {
        this.CreatedBy = "";
        this.ModifiedBy = "";
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int AttributeTypeId { get; set; }
    public int JobDetailId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> ModifiedDate { get; set; }

    public virtual AttributeType AttributeType { get; set; }
    public virtual JobDetail JobDetail { get; set; }
}
```

Does anyone know why XML is being treated differently by WebApi for the PUT verb?

Comment: Try changing AttributeTypeId name to something different for testing purpose.